# Sudoku does not launch from the application menu (Invalid desktop entry file)

Tags: 18.04, games, lxde

I installed `Ubuntu 18.04.6 desktop` and then `Lubuntu-desktop`.
When I want to run a game (e.g. sudoku) it writes.

`Invalid desktop entry file:'/usr/share/applications/gnome-sudoku.desktop`

Any game isn't working. The other applications will launch without problems.

Comment: Are you sure that the game is installed?  Maybe it was removed when you changed desktop environments? Changing the DE on an installed system can add/remove a **lot** of software.  FYI: **Lubuntu** is an official flavor of Ubuntu that is packaged with LXDE, and you would not have had to change the installed DE, which can get messy.  Please edit your question with the output of `which gnome-sudoku` and `cat /usr/share/applications/gnome-sudoku.desktop`

Comment: @Nmath Yes, the game is installed. I tried to reinstall it and the problem remains. Though one game is working (AisleRiot Solitaire). I tried to install another game (only sudoku) and it isn't working eighter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

1. Check if gnome-sudoku is on your path by opening a terminal and just entering `gnome-sudoku` (under LXQT)
2. If that worked, please try to comment out `DBusActivatable=true` (or set it to false) in `/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Sudoku.desktop` (or rather `/usr/share/applications/gnome-sudoku.desktop` in your case) and restart your LXQT session (logoff+logon). You must be su to edit (e.g. `sudo nano ...`). Launch Sudoku from the application menu.

Please tell me, if that worked.

### Long version:

When looking up `/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Sudoku.desktop` you will find the following line:

```
DBusActivatable=true
```

freedesktop.org writes in their [specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#recognized-keys):

> A boolean value specifying if D-Bus activation is supported for this application. If this key is missing, the default value is false. If the value is true then implementations **should ignore the Exec** key and send a D-Bus message to launch the application. See D-Bus Activation for more information on how this works. Applications should still include Exec= lines in their desktop files for compatibility with implementations that do not understand the DBusActivatable key.

In short this means, Sudoku is not started by a plain command, but by sending a D-Bus message.

When deactivating the `DBusActivatable` entry, the `Exec` entry is used, which should work fine, though.

I strongly assume there must be an incompatibility between LXQT and Gnome regarding D-Bus and the `gnome-games` package.

I tested it without installing LXQT myself by starting `dbus-monitor`. With the switch set to `true` I can see the following message (Sudoku started via "Acitvate" method):

```
method call time=1636304012.356091 sender=:1.90 -> destination=org.gnome.Sudoku serial=7 path=/org/gnome/Sudoku; interface=org.freedesktop.Application; member=Activate
   array [
      dict entry(
         string "desktop-startup-id"
         variant             string "gtk-launch-24810-harald-desktop-gnome-sudoku-0_TIME0"
      )
   ]
```

With the switch commented out, this message does not appear, so the Exec command must be used directly.

As long as other Applications are running fine, I would not further invest time in figuring out what the exact reason for D-Bus mismatch between LXQT and Gnome is.

But if you have time, of course you can run `dbus-monitor` and maybe you find some explanation.

Comment: Thank you for your long answer. Unfortunately I don't have possibility to test it, because I put the laptop back to my coworker. That's old madam which playes games rarely, so I only uninstalled everything except AisleRiot Solitaire which was working. I will accept this answer and let you know if I have possibility to test it in the future (if she needs something and borrows me the laptop again.)

Answer (score 0):

I would reinstall the program. 99% of the time that will cure this particular problem.

Comment: I tried to reinstall it and the problem remains. Though one game is working (AisleRiot Solitaire). I tried to install another game (only sudoku) and it isn't working eighter.